# Слова, пишущиеся через дефис, считаются одним словом или двумя?

Tags: орфография

Всегда интересовал данный вопрос. Если что-то пишется через дефис, то данная комбинация букв и дефиса считается одним словом или же двумя?

Для примера я хотел бы рассмотреть правописание частиц **-то** и **-ка**. По правилу они пишутся через дефис: "Задачу-то решил?", "Принеси-ка мне попить!" и так далее. Есть ли смысл вообще выделять здесь частицу как часть речи, ведь она сливается с предыдущим словом?.. Или же всё-таки "принеси-ка" — это два слова?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если коротко, то всё зависит от конкретных слов.
Если подлиннее, то:

> § 62. Из собственно грамматических критериев выделения слова известностью в отечественной лингвистике пользуется критерий цельнооформленности А. И. Смирницкого. Согласно этому критерию сочетание морфем признается одним словом, если грамматическое оформление при помощи соответствующей служебной морфемы получает все сочетание в целом, а не каждый из его членов. Например, иван-чай — это одно слово, так как при склонении все сочетание в целом оформляется одной флексией: иван-чая, иван-чаю, а не *ивана-чая, *ивану-чаю.
> В противном случае, когда каждый член сочетания получает свое оформление, — это называется раздельнооформленностью — сочетание признается двумя словами. Например, город-герой — это два слова, ср. города-героя, городу-герою и т. д.

[В.Б. Касевич «Элементы общей лингвистики»](https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/kasevich/text.pdf)

Таким образом, упомянутые Вами частицы `-то` и `-ка` самостоятельными словами не являются.

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того, кем считается и для чего. Например, Word считает «принеси-ка» за одно слово. В словарях частицы даются отдельной статьей, иначе количество статей увеличилось бы в разы.

Answer (score 2):

Такая частица называется энклитикой и является частью слова. Написание через дефис не принципиально. Энклитика - это часть слова, которая следует за окончанием.

В русском языке ещё есть энклитика -де, а также, устаревшая -с (словоёрс).

В других языках тоже есть энклитики: в английском притяжательное `'s`, в латыни `que` и т.д.

Энклитика не зависит от падежа и может перескакивать на другой однородный член предложения. Например, в латыни `senatus populusque` или `populus senatusque`. В английском: `the secretary and president's opinion` или `the president and secretary's opinion`. Этим энклитика отличается от окончания: падеж тот же, но энклитика перескакивает на другой однородный член предложения в зависимости от их порядка. В русском: `попрыгай и побегай-ка` или `побегай и попрыгай-ка`, `вы и ваш сын-с` или `ваш сын и вы-с`.